# Splitting XML into rows (TSQL)

Tags: t-sql

I've been wrestling with this for hours and I'm completely befuddled on why it's not working. I have the following XML as a single column (a few dozen records stored this way).

```
<dsMQ1License xmlns="http://tempuri.org/dsMQ1License.xsd">
  <licenseModuleInfo>
    <module>AP</module>
    <status>1</status>
    <statusEndDate>2007-12-28T00:00:00.0000000-05:00</statusEndDate>
  </licenseModuleInfo>
  <licenseModuleInfo>
    <module>AU</module>
    <status>1</status>
    <statusEndDate>2007-12-28T00:00:00.0000000-05:00</statusEndDate>
  </licenseModuleInfo>
  <licenseModuleInfo>
    <module>CO</module>
    <status>1</status>
    <statusEndDate>2007-12-28T00:00:00.0000000-05:00</statusEndDate>
  </licenseModuleInfo>
  <licenseModuleInfo>
    <module>DO</module>
    <status>1</status>
    <statusEndDate>2007-12-28T00:00:00.0000000-05:00</statusEndDate>
  </licenseModuleInfo>
.
.
.
</dsMQ1License>
```

I want to be able to take the XML column, and turn it into rows where each column represents the inner most element.

```
+--------+--------+---------------+
| Module | Status | StatusEndDate |
+--------+--------+---------------+
| AD     |      1 | 2017-12-28    |
| AU     |      1 | 2017-12-28    |
| CO     |      1 | 2017-12-28    |
| DO     |      1 | 2017-12-28    |
+--------+--------+---------------+
```

Based on everything I've read so far, I feel like what I've done should work.

```
SELECT 
T.C.value('(module)[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)') AS ModuleAbbr
,T.C.value('(status)[1]','bit') AS Active
FROM LicenseXML
CROSS APPLY LicenseXML.License.nodes('/dsMQ1License/licenseModuleInfo') T(C)
```

But it just returns 0 rows.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
 DECLARE @x xml = '<dsMQ1License xmlns="http://tempuri.org/dsMQ1License.xsd">

  <licenseModuleInfo>

    <module>AP</module>

    <status>1</status>

    <statusEndDate>2007-12-28T00:00:00.0000000-05:00</statusEndDate>

  </licenseModuleInfo>

  <licenseModuleInfo>

    <module>AU</module>

    <status>1</status>

    <statusEndDate>2007-12-28T00:00:00.0000000-05:00</statusEndDate>

  </licenseModuleInfo>

  <licenseModuleInfo>

    <module>CO</module>

    <status>1</status>

    <statusEndDate>2007-12-28T00:00:00.0000000-05:00</statusEndDate>

  </licenseModuleInfo>

  <licenseModuleInfo>

    <module>DO</module>

    <status>1</status>

    <statusEndDate>2007-12-28T00:00:00.0000000-05:00</statusEndDate>

  </licenseModuleInfo>

</dsMQ1License>'



;WITH XMLNAMESPACES

(

DEFAULT 'http://tempuri.org/dsMQ1License.xsd' 

)

    SELECT 

    x.item.value('module[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS ModuleAbbr

    ,x.item.value('status[1]','bit') AS Active

    ,x.item.value('statusEndDate[1]','datetime') AS EndDate

    FROM @x.nodes('//dsMQ1License/licenseModuleInfo') AS x(item)
```

Comment: Thanks, this led me to the right answer. I'm using a series of sub-queries to actually get the XML and I wasn't able to get your solution to work with those sub queries, but I noticed you defined the namespaces, which after a few hours I was able to get working. I've added my own post with the solution I ended up using.

Comment: As you have not provided the table structure, i have declared that xml as variable

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a WITH statement and some subqueries to actually find the license. In the end, defining the namespace and using the namespace alias is what made this work.

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://tempuri.org/dsMQ1License.xsd' AS ns)
,LicenseXML AS (
SELECT CAST(License AS XML) AS License
    FROM (
        SELECT a.i.value('.','varchar(max)') AS License
        FROM 
            (SELECT CAST(memLicense AS XML) memLicense FROM tblMQ1SysLicense) AS X
            CROSS APPLY X.memLicense.nodes('/License') AS a(i)
        ) AS LicXML
)
SELECT 
T.C.value('ns:module[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)') AS ModuleAbbr
,T.C.value('ns:status[1]','bit') AS Active
,T.C.value('ns:statusEndDate[1]','DATE') AS StatusDate
FROM LicenseXML
CROSS APPLY LicenseXML.License.nodes('/ns:dsMQ1License/ns:licenseModuleInfo') T(C)
```